# linphone - error when build: undefined reference

Tags: android, linphone

I built linphone-android on ubuntu 14.04 (I use source from homepage) and got some trouble. Here they are:

---

> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/msamr/src/msamr.c:42: error: undefined reference to 'opencore_amr_wrapper_init'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:30: error: undefined reference to 'my_GSMInitDecode'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:35: error: undefined reference to 'my_GSMDecodeFrameExit'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:44: error: undefined reference to 'my_AMRDecode'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:56: error: undefined reference to 'my_AMREncodeInit'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:62: error: undefined reference to 'my_AMREncodeExit'
>
> /home/com08/linphone-android//jni/..//submodules/externals/build/opencore-amr/../../opencore-amr/amrnb/wrapper.cpp:69: error: undefined reference to 'my_AMREncode'

---

I got this error for several days but I couldn't fix them. Do you have any ideas? I've installed libxml2-dev already.
Thank you.

Comment: What commands did you type when building?

Comment: @meneldal: I used $make.

Comment: There's no configure script to run before?

Comment: No, there isn't. I follow README file in the project. And I just run $make after I installed some package like: automake, yasm, nasm... Do I miss something?

Comment: Might be a problem with the wrong version of a library. That's the most likely thing to happen if there's no "file no found" error.

Comment: @meneldal: I just updated my question. I followed this link: [link](https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-94176) and I got that. I have no idea about that. Can you giev me some advices?

Comment: You're not getting any error/warning from step 5 to 7?

Comment: No, I'm not. Because I replaced "prepare_sources.sh" by "check_tools.sh".  Am I right?

Comment: Why did you do that? "prepare_sources" is probably required for the build to completely correctly

Comment: ops!! actually I didn't see "prepare_sources.sh" in folder. Just had "check_tools.sh". in the source folder just had "check_tools.sh", but no "prepare_sources.sh". I didn't replace a file by a file. :P.. I didn't say clearly..

Comment: Looking at the date of the post it's 2 years old so you might want to check the readme on the git here: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android Try to follow those instructions

Comment: [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so
the project got trouble when building this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can build i without error:
(p.s: I do all in project folder. Use `cd /your/path/to/linphone-android`)

> - use ndk r10c
> - use source: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android
> - clean project:    `git clean -xfd`
> - update submodule:    `git submodule update --init --recursive`
> - `ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-x` (x is your current API)
> - run    `$make`